# How to make EditText not empty?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an editText and button. EditText is for users' names. I have a problem, my code below.

```
 String fullname = editText.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

My problem is when the user clicks on the button without putting anything, toast message show; which is fine but when the user put space it stores fullname value empty. I don't want empty value.

Comment: You can check for spaces like this `editText.getText().toString().contains(" ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trim the input: `fullname.trim().isEmpty()` to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace. So if you have an input with just whitespace, it will consider it empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the button when the text is invalid. It's better to validate earlier rather than allow an action prematurely. It's also possible, using the `TextWatcher` to modify the user input to remove invalid spaces etc.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/ok"/>
```

In activity or fragment:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(
            object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                    button.isEnabled = s.trim().isNotEmpty()
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

            }
    )
```